# Custom class for data arranged in tree fashion

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a custom class that arrange data in the following fashion:-

```
Departments 
        Section 1
                 Person 1
                 Person 2
        Section 2
        ... etc
```

Below is the code i wrote but it is not working as i'm thinking:-

```
    public class Sections
    {
        private List<Section> _Section = new List<Section>();
        public List<Section> Section
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Section;
            }
        }
    }
    //Innehåller alla detailer om varje sektion
    public class Section
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
        public int MinimumStaffing { get; set; }
        public int IdealStaffing { get; set; }

        private List<Person> _Employee = new List<Person>();
        public List<Person> Employee
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Employee;
            }
            set { }
        }
    }
    //Innehåller alla info. om en enskild personal
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int TelephoneNo { get; set; }
        public int Pager { get; set; }
        public int HomePhone { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

What i'm trying to do is:-
First:- get the name of Section 1 and save it to a string.
Second:- get the name of each person in this section (Section 1).
Third:- add both the name of Section 1 and the list of persons in this section to the list Named Departments.

Below is the code that i'm using to achieve what i'm trying to do (Which is not working for me, see below for more info)

```
if (index == 0 || index == node.ChildNodes.Count)
                        {
                            if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 2)
                            {
                                sektionsNamn = node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                                continue;
                            }
                            else if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 2)
                            {
                                Sektion.Employee.Add(new Person() { Name = node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText });
                                index = node.ChildNodes.Count;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Sektioner.Section.Add(new Section() { Name = sektionsNamn, Employee=Sektion.Employee });
                            index = 0;
                        }
```

the problem is with the else statment, it returns 0 counts, i.e it adds the Name property, but it doesn't add the employee list.

Any idea how to overcome this??

Sorry for bothering and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property setter for `Employee` property in the `Section` class is empty, therefore you do not assign anything to `_Employee` when you call it like this `Sektioner.Section.Add(new Section() { Name = sektionsNamn, Employee=Sektion.Employee })`. In your example you have this code for `Employee` property:

```
public List<Person> Employee
{
     get
     {
           return this._Employee;
     }
     set { }
}
```

You should change it to this code (i.e. implement the property setter)

```
public List<Person> Employee
{
       get
       {
            return this._Employee;
       }
       set 
       { 
            this._Employee = value;
       }
}
```

Also, I recommend you to implement the constructor in your class `Section` that will set the field within its block:

```
public class Section
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
        public int MinimumStaffing { get; set; }
        public int IdealStaffing { get; set; }
        public Section(string name, List<Person> employee)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this._Employee = employee;
        }
        public Section()
        {
            this._Employee = new List<Person>(); //if you call the empty constructor, create the list
        }
        private List<Person> _Employee; 
        public List<Person> Employee
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Employee;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Employee = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

and then you can change your call to:

```
Sektioner.Section.Add(new Section(sektionsNamn, Sektion.Employee));
```

Which I find is more straightforward and rarely leads to similar errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is exactly was what i wanted. Many thanks

Comment: After testing this, just found that Sektion.Employee keeps adding person names even after the SektionsNamn is changed. Which ends up with 5 section that contains the same no. of persons, which is not what i want. My sections is like Section 1 have 4 persons, while section 2 have 6 persons. If i use Sektion.Employee.Clear() i ends up with 5 sections but 0 person i those. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Sry to bother i found a solution tho i don't know if it is the best practic, but for me it sounds logical. I instantiate Sektion by adding Sektion=new section(); after i added items to Sektioner list.

Comment: @DreamNet You're not bothering but I couldn't quite understand the first question. I'll help you if you need something.